# check for a pre commit hook string , SVN

Tags: git, bash, svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I wanted to check if a string "XYZ" in present in SVN commit message in pre-commit hook. I have tried below code :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

set SVNLOOK="%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe"

SET M=

REM Concatenate all the lines in the commit message
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%g IN (`%SVNLOOK% log -t %TXN% %REPOS%`) DO SET    M=!M!%%g



if [[ $M == * "XYZ"* ]] then
goto NORMAL_EXIT
else
:ERROR_TOO_SHORT
echo "Commit id missing .Please enter the commit id in the format [XYZ - number]";
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
fi



REM All checks passed, so allow the commit.
:NORMAL_EXIT
exit 0
```

But when i commit in SVN i am getting $M was unexpected at this time. Where am i going wrong ?

EDIT: it works good for this code only ,

```
REM Make sure M is defined
SET M=0%M%

REM Here the 6 is the length we require
IF NOT "%M:~6,1%"=="" goto NORMAL_EXIT

:ERROR_TOO_SHORT
echo "Commit note must be at least 6 letters" >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
exit /b 1
```

If i try to modify this to check string using if..else then it breaks.

Comment: This is not a Bash program, and it is not a Windows batch program either. It looks like you have mixed up different snippets.

Comment: Yeah, i just took it from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386934/checking-for-specific-string-in-commit-message-svn-precommit-hook

And i tried to edit it for my requirement .

Comment: OK, that one is a Unix shell script, but yours contains lots of Windows batch syntax.

Comment: OK I think it is more clear now with that last edit you made.

Comment: Yeah, but i looked at a Unix tutorial and found this for unix,

[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/if-else-statement.htm)

And edited this to my use.

Comment: Any help with this ?